# Sharepoint and OneDrive ios apps not working together?

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, app, onedrive-for-business, apple-ios

I'm running sharepoint on-prem 2016.

Hi everyone. I'm having an issue with mysites onedrive and the onedrive app. When I hit share, I'm not able to share with AD users as if I were on the computer. I can only share a link VIA email.

On the flipside, If I use the sharepoint app, i'm able to do everything out of there fine, but when I set the mysites to modern (and not the horrible imbedded website view), i'm unable to view the side menu in order to view shared with me.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, if i try to share out of one note, i get the error cannot share with external email addresses. I can't find anything anywhere to enable this. Everything i find is for sharepoint online.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though this is just how it is at the moment. Microsoft does appear to be updating their sharepoint apps a lot more often now though.